# Pages 5 for iOS 7 not syncing

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, ios, pages

Pages 5 on my iPad and iPod does not seem to be syncing with iCloud, while my Mac is. I've tried everything there is online. Yes, my Documents and Data is on for iCloud, I've tried resetting Documents and Data, etc. They won't download them from iCloud and won't upload. The documents have an upload icon on them, but they won't upload.
Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing the following:

Remember to backup every file through email if not already synced with iCloud.

1. Disable and then enable iCloud sync for Pages in the Settings app under Pages section, it's located in `Preferences - Pages`, the switch is labelled `Use iCloud`. *Quit the app through launcher before disabling, launch the app after disabling, and then quit it before enabling again.*
2. Disable and then enable document syncing for Pages app under `Preferences - iCloud - Documents and Data`, the switch is labelled `Pages`. Do the same thing in italic as in (1).
3. Delete the app and then install it again.
4. Disable and then enable system-wide Documents & Data syncing under `Preferences - iCloud`. Do the same thing in italic as in (a).
5. Delete iCloud account from iPhone and then add it again. It can be done under `Preferences - iCloud`.

Comment: I've done all these before (and I did them again), with no luck. They don't seem to actually be stored in the Pages app. When I go into iTunes to seed Pages documents, only one of them show up. The same thing happens with iExplorer. When I go to developer.icloud.com, it only shows the ones from my Mac. If I could find where these files are really stored, that might fix my problem. Even when I delete the app, my documents don't disappear. Thanks!

Comment: The files are stored, like the Mac version, in MobileDocuments folder which is handled by iOS/OS X.

Comment: If worst comes to worst, restore.